# Fill HttpPostedFileBase variable in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I read a file from folder `~/Content/PDFfiles` and put it into a `HttpPostedFileBase` variable?

`Myclass`:

```
public class myclass
{
    public long id { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase myfile { get; set; }
}
```

I want to read `sita.pdf` from `~/Content/PDFfiles` and store its contents in `myfile`.

Comment: you can't but , you have path to file so you can return path and then request using that url to server which will give the pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The `HttpPostedFileBase` is intended to be used by clients that are uploading files to the server. It is a special class that is populated by the framework when some client uploads a file to the server.

It is unclear what exactly are you trying to achieve in the first place. If you are trying to send a PDF file to the client, then you should have a controller action that simply returns a FileResult:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string file = Server.MapPath("Content/PDFfiles/sita.pdf");
    return File(file, "application/pdf", "sita.pdf");
}
```

and then you could have some link inside the view that will allow the user to download this file:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download PDF", "Download")
```